# Language injection intelliJ, cant find where to enable it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I accidentally disabled the option for Language injection so now i can't find the way how to enable it again

[image: I tried to find it here but no luck...]

Answer (score 1):

Help -> Find Action... and type "Language injection" and press enter you'll all the settings related to Language injection.

or press `Ctrl+Shift+A` and type "Language injection"  and press enter